# Notepad++ and UTF-8

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, notepad++

I have a problem with Notepad++ and special characters.

File - New with UTF-8 encoding

Input: §äÄöÖüÜ
as Hex: c2 a7 c3 a4 c3 84 c3 b6 c3 96 c3 bc c3 9c

Where the additional characters come?

I discovered the problem when inserting a password.

Answer (score 2):

What you show as hex are not characters, but bytes. They're just the UTF-8 encoded representation of those characters. A UTF-8 character can be up to 4 bytes long, the 7 characters here seem to take two bytes each - therefore the result is 14 bytes.

If you don't want multiple bytes per character you'll need to use another encoding. Judging by that set of characters `latin-1` might be a good guess, but obviously you should confirm what encoding whatever you're feeding that data into wants.

Comment: Thanks! It is not a problem with Notepad++ but a PHP + UTF-8 + MySQL trouble.